# Relocate a linked program

Tags: linker, elf, relocation

Is it possible to relocate an already linked elf file to another address and update internal references too ?

For example, having a statically linked elf file linked at 0x50000, how can I move it to 0x1000000 and update pointers & addresses ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to relocate an already linked elf file to another address

In general: no. The linker discards relocation records, required to update internal references within the executable.

Now, *if* your executable uses no global data and doesn't take addresses of any functions, *and* you are on an architecture where `JMP`s and `CALL`s are `pc`-relative, then it might be possible to just update the `PT_LOAD` segments and `.e_entry` in the `Elf{32,64}_Ehdr`.